# Does BluetoothLE mess up Timer timing?

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, avfoundation

My app makes use of Timers to playback multiple audio files at the same time.

To give the audio maximum priority, the AVAudioSession uses the `.playAndRecord` category and allows for airplay and bluetooth.

The timers are set up like this and are given priority over the user interface inside the app (table view stutters slightly while scrolling, otherwise audio playback would stop while scrolling), all user interaction outside the app is not affected:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false, block: { _ in
  RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common) 
}
```

This makes sure that the timers work properly even when the device is locked.

Please don't tell me that Timers aren't precise enough, for audio playback they are, they seem to work fine to the point of a few milliseconds.

This works fine over airplay (with the usual small delay) and common bluetooth speakers (they seem to use bluetoothA2DP).

However though, I've found that when using bluetooth in my VW car (which uses bluetoothLE i.e. low energy) really messes up the timing of the timers. They all fire in the correct order but they aren't anywhere precise anymore.

Does bluetoothLE affect the timers and is there a way to circumvent this?

On a side note, it seems to also crush the audio quality bitwise.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, setting the `AVAudioSession` category to `.playback` fixes the issue completely.
The previous setting of `.playAndRecord` seems to allow for more available resources in locked state but has the opposite effect for BluetoothLE connections.

For now I'll simply be switching between `AVAudioSession` categories when the audio routing changes.